# Bug in excel when using values property with filtered list

Tags: vba, excel

I've run into something I'm guessing is a nasty bug in Excel, but not sure.

Strangely enough, I've never seen this before, despite 10 years developing in VBA for Excel. Works the same way in Excel 2010 and 2013 for PC.

How to reproduce:

1. New Workbook.
2. Add a couple of column headers (Column 1-6) in cells a1:f1
3. Add a few values (at least 2 different values) in the first column ("A" or "B") in cells a2:a8
4. Add a filter to row 1 and select an item from the filter in Col A
5. Hide column C
6. Run the following macro:

   ```
   Public Sub test()
       Dim rng As Range
       Dim v As Variant
       Dim i As Long
       i = 1
       ReDim v(1 To i, 1 To 6)
       v(1, 1) = "x"
       v(1, 2) = "x1"
       v(1, 3) = "x2"
       v(1, 4) = "x3"
       v(1, 5) = "x4"
       v(1, 6) = "x5"
       Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A9:F9")
       If i = 2 Then
           v(2, 1) = "y"
           v(2, 2) = "y1"
           v(2, 3) = "y2"
           v(2, 4) = "y3"
           v(2, 5) = "y4"
           v(2, 6) = "y5"
           Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A9:F10")
       End If
       rng.Value = v
   End Sub
   ```

What now happens is the following, depending on the value of i.

i=1:

```
A9="x"
B9="x1"
C9=unchanged
D9:F9="x"
```

i=2:

```
A9="x"
B9="x1"
C9=unchanged
D9="x"
E9="x3"
F9="#VALUE"
```

(row 10 is then similar to 9 but with "y" instead)

i=1 at least seems to repeat the first value after the first hidden column.
For i=2 I have no idea what it's doing.

From my point of view this looks ***incredibly*** buggy.

Comment: I was able to replicate your scenario when I added more text other than `Blah Blah`

Comment: Yeah, I guess I missed a few other specific details I didn't think matter. The error seems to not appear if the filter contains the new cells, so the filter needs to be added first.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post to add more details on reproducing the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a reason as to why is it behaving like this...

Comment: Tried every trick I'm aware of... looks like this has been [posted before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10354564/2521004) with similar results.