# Saving and restoring autofilter criteria, trouble with dates

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Two subs below; you can save the autofilter criteria on a table and restore them at any point.

```
Public Sub SaveFilter()
    Dim Value As Variant
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim Arr As Variant
    ReDim Arr(0)
    Dim t As Variant

    Set cocoll = New Collection
    Set crcoll = New Collection

    With shMain.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter
        If .FilterMode Then
            For c = 1 To .Filters.Count
                If .Filters(c).On Then
                    If IsArray(.Filters(c).Criteria1) Then
                        For Each Value In .Filters(c).Criteria1
                            Arr(UBound(Arr)) = Mid(Value, 2, Len(Value))
                            ReDim Preserve Arr(UBound(Arr) + 1)
                        Next
                        ReDim Preserve Arr(UBound(Arr) - 1)
                    Else
                        Arr(UBound(Arr)) = .Filters(c).Criteria1
                        ReDim Preserve Arr(UBound(Arr) + 1)
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Arr(UBound(Arr)) = .Filters(c).Criteria2
                        If Err <> 0 Then ReDim Preserve Arr(UBound(Arr) - 1)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    End If

                    cocoll.Add Arr
                    crcoll.Add c
                    ReDim Arr(0)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With

    shMain.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub

Public Sub RestoreFilter()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To crcoll.Count
        shMain.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=crcoll.item(i)
        shMain.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=crcoll.item(i), Criteria1:=cocoll.item(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here's the problem: it throws an error as soon as I try to filter on a date column. I've tried several formats like "yyyy/mm/dd", "dd/mm/yyyy", "mm/dd/yyyy". I figured I could try the "General" NumberFormat but if it's already filtered I can't turn the NumberFormat for all hidden rows into General.

Answer (score 1):

I have found several threads with this issue. It appears to be a limitation in Excel. Please refer to the following urls:

- [Error 1004 when trying to get AutoFilter criteria of date filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307045/error-1004-when-trying-to-get-autofilter-criteria-of-date-filtering)

I have found several solutions that would work in my situation:

- Setting ActiveWindow.AutoFilterDateGrouping = False. This will change the autofilter treeview [Excel VBA Saving autofilter settings with dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328968/excel-vba-saving-autofilter-settings-with-dates).
- Extracting the dates from XML: [Get Date Autofilter in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040238/get-date-autofilter-in-excel-vba/32062115#32062115)
- When filtering on dates in the tree view this does not get added to criteria1 or criteria2, instead, you could use date filters.