# Can't restore filter criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know the total number of row and for that I need to have all the datas, so no filter in headers.

But after that, I want to restore the filter with their criteria. I used this code:

```
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim filterArray()
    Dim currentFiltRange As String
    Dim col As Integer

    Set w = ActiveSheet

    ' Capture AutoFilter settings
    With w.AutoFilter
        currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
        With .Filters
            ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
            For f = 1 To .Count
                With .Item(f)
                    If .On Then
                        'It stop here
                        filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                        If .Operator Then
                            filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                            filterArray(f, 3) = .Criteria2 'simply delete this line to make it work in Excel 2010
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next f
        End With
    End With

    'Remove AutoFilter
    w.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Your code here

    ' Restore Filter settings
    For col = 1 To UBound(filterArray(), 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(filterArray(col, 1)) Then
            If filterArray(col, 2) Then
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1), _
                Operator:=filterArray(col, 2), _
                Criteria2:=filterArray(col, 3)
            Else
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next col
```

But it doesn't work. For example, I want all datas for the month of June and I have this error:

error 1004 - Application-defined or Object-defined error

I tried to get the criteria by using:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Autofilter.filters.Item(1).Criteria1
```

Still doesn't work, same error. But I noticed it only work for "simple" criteria such as "empty" or "equal to something specific".

How can I fix that ?

Comment: It seems that this is a problem with date date filter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307045/error-1004-when-trying-to-get-autofilter-criteria-of-date-filtering Honestly; i have no solution for you

Comment: Thank you, yes it seems not possible or too complicated for a Tree view control.