# How can I store filter and sorting settings after run time and resort them later?

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, filtering

How can I store Excel filter and sorting settings after run time so I can set them up later. In other words, a user sets up a filter and sort he likes and he wants to store it for use on some other day. He can then call up and use that sort and filter setup again when he wants it.

I have over 2000 rows and 700 columns with data so a simple exclusion of one value would mean I would have 1999 criteria for one filter on one column. Here is an example using just five rows excluding just one value. You can see how the characters will build up fast if I have 700 x 2000:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$4:$B$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("1", _
    "2", "3", "5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Also note that this solution below found online does the run time save and restore (NOT what I want):

[In Excel VBA, how do I save / restore a user-defined filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter/9490281#9490281)

```
Sub ReDoAutoFilter()
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim filterArray()
Dim currentFiltRange As String
Dim col As Integer

Set w = ActiveSheet

' Capture AutoFilter settings
With w.AutoFilter
    currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
    With .Filters
        ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
        For f = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(f)
                If .On Then

                    filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                    If .Operator Then

                        filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                        filterArray(f, 3) = .Criteria2 'simply delete this line to make it work in Excel 2010
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next f
    End With
End With

'Remove AutoFilter
w.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Your code here


' Restore Filter settings
For col = 1 To UBound(filterArray(), 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(filterArray(col, 1)) Then
        If filterArray(col, 2) Then

            w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter Field:=col, _
            Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1), _
            Operator:=filterArray(col, 2), _
            Criteria2:=filterArray(col, 3)
        Else
            w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter Field:=col, _
            Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next col
 End Sub
```

I can probably use a modified version of the restore part above, but I have to save permanently/after run time.

My thoughts were:

1) save criteria in one cell per column criteria: the 255 character limit per cell excludes this as an option. Comments have the same character limit.

2) save criteria in multiple cells per column criteria: too messy

3) (this would be the best) save criteria and header names in a sheet and actually apply the criteria without the data: I can't get that to work (note that the data set is too big to save the entire thing with the data to preserve the filter and sort criteria)

4) So now I am thinking I have to write these criteria to a text file, which I'd like to avoid...hence, my question.

Is there a better way that I am not finding or thinking of?

PS - It has been stipulated that I must write everything in VBA, no databases or other languages please.

Thanks!

Comment: Re point 1:In modern versions of Excel, VBA can write a string of up to 32767 characters to a cell (tested in Excel 2010)

Comment: We just upgraded all our PCs to Excel 2010, so that should work. Guess I was still living in the stone age. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

chris neilsen (first comment on my question):"Re point 1:In modern versions of Excel, VBA can write a string of up to 32767 characters to a cell (tested in Excel 2010"

That solves it for me.