# Clear all filters from an Excel-Table and reapply it?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to clear all filters from an Excel-table, do something else inbetween, and then reapply the filters with the same criteria as before?

Comment: See the answers to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Answer (score 1):

use like below

```
 Activesheet.EnableAutoFilter = True
```

or for Particular range

```
   Activesheet.Range("A6:R6").AutoFilter = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This page should show you what you need: [Autofilter in VBA](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm)