# Range.Find fails on ranges that are both hidden AND part of a filter

Tags: vba, excel

I'm experiencing a peculiar problem in Excel 2003 where the Range.Find method fails when searching for a value in a cell that is both hidden and part of a filtered range.

To be clear, this is the method call in question:

```
Cells.Find(SearchString, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

- If the cell containing SearchString is merely hidden, Range.Find works.
- If the cell containing SearchString is merely part of a filtered range (but not hidden), Range.Find works.
- If the cell containing SearchString is both hidden (by a filter or otherwise), AND is part of a filtered range, Range.Find fails.

Many sources on various Excel sites and forums claim that specifying "LookIn:=xlFormulas" will force Range.Find to search within hidden cells. Though nonsensical, that seems to be true if SearchString is in a cell that is *merely* hidden. If the cell is *both* hidden and part of a filtered range, it fails.

Note that it doesn't matter if the cell is being hidden *by the filter*. For example, you can search for the *heading* of a filtered range (which will never be hidden by the filter itself), but if that heading happens to be in a column you've hidden, Range.Find will fail.

Is there any Excel method that will just reliably search cells without regard for whether or not they happen to be hidden and/or part of a filter?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to work it around (not possible without changing the native behaviour of `AutoFilter`; what we cannot). Otherwise, when you copy / paste from there, you would also copy entries not included using the current filter. For excel those entries are temporarily "unknown" (that is the purpose of the filter). Is it possible for you to _temporally_ remove the filter and restore it after doing all your searches? [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9489126/4352306) has lots of useful answers to achieve that. Perhaps you could use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

More detail would be helpful

- for a 1D range you could use `Match`
- for 2D a variant array either looking through each element of the array, or applying `MATCH` to each column of the array

Samples below
*1D*

```
Sub D1()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("C5:C100")
Dim StrTest As String
Dim X As Variant

StrTest = "Filtered"

X = Application.Match(StrTest, rng1, 0)
If IsError(X) Then
    MsgBox "no match"
Else
    MsgBox "Found in position " & X
    Set rng2 = rng1.Cells(X)
End If
End Sub

Sub D2()
```

*2D*

```
Dim X
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim StrTest As String


X = Range("C5:D100").Value2
StrTest = "Filtered"

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
        If X(lngRow, lngCol) = StrTest Then
         Set rng1 = [c5].Offset(lngRow - 1, lngCol - 1)
         MsgBox "Found in position " & rng1.Address
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```