# Excel VBA, Writing from array to list object, including cells hidden by filters

Tags: arrays, excel, autofilter, listobject, vba

I'm working in Excel 2013, writing a macro in VBA, and I'm trying to assign a value to all of the cells in a column of a list object (table), including some that may be hidden by the filters. Assigning a value to each cell individually seemed to be slowing the process down considerably, and I found a suggestion to copy the range into a variant array, iterate over the array to change the values, and then copy the array back to the range.

```
varray = table.DataBodyRange.Columns(columnIndex).Value
For i = 1 to UBound(varray, 1)
    If (condition) then
        varray(i, 1) = i
    End If
Next i
table.DataBodyRange.Columns(columnIndex).Value = varray
```

For the most part, this works and solves the speed issue. It stops working when there is a filter on any column in the table. So far as I can tell, the array will still be copied from the table correctly, but does not copy back correctly. All cells before the first cell hidden by the filter will be handled correctly, but the cells hidden will not be changed, and any cells after hidden cells will be set to the first value in the array.

This only occurs when the cells are hidden by the filter, and not when rows of the worksheet are hidden.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a way to properly reapply the array despite the filter? If not, is there a way to temporarily remove the filter, make the changes, and then put the same filter back in place? Or just a better way to do this that doesn't sacrifice speed?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you remove the filter and apply it back when done? Also, try https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-functionality-during-macro-execution#t=201608192213553239107

Comment: I have considered removing the filter and reapplying it, but I don't know how to get information about the current filter. And I already had screenupdating and calculation turned off, and I just tried it with events disabled, and it isn't significantly faster.

Comment: This question is not the duplicate of that. The acutal problem is the Excel bug leading to incorrect results of setting data to a filtered range. **There is the efficient work around**: writing a variant array to a temporary unfiltered range and then writing data to a destination range from the latter. See [Excel 2013 VBA Bug when copying variant array to range of cells in a filtered table](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/excel-2013-vba-bug-when-copying-variant-array-to/0e176ce8-fbbd-4a84-8673-e57ee5cc25af).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found code on another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter) that captures the auto-filter state.

```
Sub ReDoAutoFilter()
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim filterArray()
    Dim currentFiltRange As String
    Dim col As Integer

Set w = ActiveSheet

' Capture AutoFilter settings
With w.AutoFilter
    currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
    With .Filters
        ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
        For f = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(f)
                If .On Then
                    filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                    If .Operator Then
                        filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                        filterArray(f, 3) = .Criteria2 'simply delete this line to make it work in Excel 2010
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next f
    End With
End With

'Remove AutoFilter
w.AutoFilterMode = False

' Your code here

' Restore Filter settings
For col = 1 To UBound(filterArray(), 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(filterArray(col, 1)) Then
        If filterArray(col, 2) Then
            w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
            Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1), _
            Operator:=filterArray(col, 2), _
            Criteria2:=filterArray(col, 3)
        Else
            w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
            Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next col
End Sub
```

A known issue is that it is unable to find a way to capture date filters where the criteria is based on selection from the Tree View control in the Filter drop-down.

Comment: Thanks! I think this workaround will work for me, but I wish I knew what was going wrong in the first place