# In Excel VBA is it possible to differentiate between filtered hidden rows and manually hidden cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write some VBA code that unhides all rows that have been hidden with a macro (Rows.Hidden = True), but which leaves rows hidden by filters alone. Is this possible? I can't find a way to differentiate between the two.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Un-hide all then reapply the filter.

Comment: Can the filter be reapplied in code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Comment: Found this for reapply filter:

Comment: ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter. Seems to be working fine, thank you for the help!