# Reactivate AutoFilter with specific filtering options

Tags: vba, excel

For an Excel macro to work properly I need to show all currently filtered entries, which I do with:

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

After the code has run I would like to reenable the precise filtering options that were active before I disabled them. Is this at all possible?

I also tried to turn off the AutoFilter and turn it back on, hoping that it would remember the settings, but that wasn't the case.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried searching? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Comment: yes, i did. probably my phrasing was wrong. thank you.