# How do I get Filter Criteria in Excel 2016 using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an Excel 2016 VBA Macro that applies a filter to the headings column. Afterwards, the user applies the filter criteria. I would like to be able to in VBA retrieve the filter criteria that the user applied and save it to a string array. Is there a way to access the filter criteria?

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/333961-capture-autofilter-state.html (linked from mmurietta's linked post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter) and pretty much copied the first part of the code, the only thing is you don't get the field that it is applied to which can be problematic.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet
With sht.AutoFilter
    With .Filters
        ReDim filtarr(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
        For f = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(f)
                If .On Then
                    filtarr(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                    Debug.Print .Criteria1
                    If .Operator Then
                        filtarr(f, 2) = .Operator
                        filtarr(f, 3) = .Criteria2
                        Debug.Print .Operator & ", " & .Criteria2
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next f
    End With
End With
```

Comment: (a) "the field that it is applied to" - isn't that determinable by `sht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(f).Column` (i.e. the column in the worksheet that is `Columns(f)` of the filtered range) (b) The code will need to be tweaked a bit if the user is selecting a list of values in a field rather than just one or two values (`Criteria1` in that case will be a Variant array, which could be accessed by `filtarr(f,1)(1)`, `filtarr(f,1)(2)`, etc)

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am having issues executing the line With .Filters. The error is: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: @MaxTither - you first need to test whether `sht.AutoFilter` is not `Nothing` - if there's no Autofilter applied then you cannot access its `Filters` property

Comment: In the end, I did not end up using this method to solve my problem, Instead I used a pivot table. I will take your word that it is a solution. Thank you @mmurrietta

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add a bit to the discussion.  I found this (and other excellent sources of help) when investigating how to "return" the filter status.  In my case, I want to DISPLAY the filter status in a cell on a worksheet.

As I said, this question and many others like it were quite useful.  From that, I was able to build the function shown in the code below.

I pass it the name of the Table for which I want the filter status... thus it's passed in as a RANGE and it then needs to look in the PARENT (sheet) for information.  This is because there may be several Tables on the SHEET from which it comes, so I can't just use the SHEET itself to get Autofilter information.

This works well, except for one thing:  if the active cell on the worksheet is NOT within the table in question, the function will see the number of filters as zero (WholeTable.Parent.Autofilter.Filters.Count in the sample below). I do not understand why this is, nor how to prevent it.  If the active cell IS within the table range, it works perfectly.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Code:

---

```
Public Function AutoFilterCriteria(ByVal WholeTable As Range) As String

On Error Resume Next

If WholeTable.Parent.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then                     ' if no filter is applied
    AutoFilterCriteria = "None"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
End If

Dim LongStr As String, FirstOne As Boolean
LongStr = ""
FirstOne = False

Dim iFilt As Integer
For iFilt = 1 To WholeTable.Parent.AutoFilter.Filters.Count         ' loop through each column of the table
    Dim ThisFilt As Filter
    Set ThisFilt = WholeTable.Parent.AutoFilter.Filters(iFilt)      ' look at each filter
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisFilt
        If .On Then
            If FirstOne Then LongStr = LongStr & " AND "            ' Get column title
            LongStr = LongStr & "[" & WholeTable.Parent.Cells(WholeTable.Row - 1, WholeTable.Column + iFilt - 1).Value & ":"
            On Error GoTo Handle
            If .Operator = xlFilterValues Then                      ' dont really care to enumerate multiples, just show "multiple"
                LongStr = LongStr & "<Multiple>]"
            ElseIf .Operator = 0 Then
                LongStr = LongStr & .Criteria1 & "]"
            ElseIf .Operator = xlAnd Then
                LongStr = LongStr & .Criteria1 & " AND " & .Criteria2 & "]"
            ElseIf .Operator = xlOr Then
                LongStr = LongStr & .Criteria1 & " OR " & .Criteria2 & "]"
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            FirstOne = True
        End If
    End With
Next

AutoFilterCriteria = LongStr
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

Handle:
AutoFilterCriteria = "! Error !"
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Fixed.See answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291924/finding-the-status-of-arbitrarily-applied-autofilter-in-excel-2016)

Answer (score 0):

the code would to be like this. The code of field is  cells(1, f).

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet
With sht.AutoFilter
    With .Filters
        ReDim filtarr(1 To .Count, 1 To 4) ' change array
        For f = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(f)
                If .On Then
                    filtarr(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                    filtarr(f, 4) = Cells(1, f) 'field
                    Debug.Print .Criteria1, Cells(1, f)
                    If .Operator Then
                        filtarr(f, 2) = .Operator
                        filtarr(f, 3) = .Criteria2

                        Debug.Print .Operator & ", " & .Criteria2
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next f
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

02/02/2024 :
I have a code working with Office 365.
I take days to find a solution working on multiple value filters. Youhoo!
It seems that I don t have a bug when the cursor is out from the data, like others has get.
Please find here my code :

```
Sub Bouton1_Cliquer() ' Get Filters : Right button
  Dim NameWorksheetDCT As String
  Dim OutTblRef As String
  NameWorksheetDCT = ActiveSheet.Range("W3").Text
  OutTblRef = "AA1"
  ActiveSheet.Range(ExtendRangeCell(OutTblRef, 2, 11)).ClearContents
  Call GetFiltersFromTbl(Worksheets(NameWorksheetDCT).Range(ActiveSheet.Range("Y3").Text), ActiveSheet.Range(OutTblRef))
End Sub
Sub Bouton1S_Cliquer() ' Set Filters : Right button
  Dim NameWorksheetDCT As String
  Dim OutTblRef As String
  NameWorksheetDCT = ActiveSheet.Range("W3").Text
  OutTblRef = "AA1"
  If MsgBox("Etes vous sure de reseter et modifier les filtres du tableau ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub:
  Call SetFiltersFromTbl(Worksheets(NameWorksheetDCT).Range(ActiveSheet.Range("Y3").Text), ActiveSheet.Range(OutTblRef))
End Sub
Sub GetFiltersFromTbl(InTbl As Range, RecFilt As Range)
  Dim Str As String
  Dim InputRange As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim a As Integer
  Dim i As Integer: Dim ii As Integer
  Dim nbr_col As Integer

  i = 0: ii = 0
  Do While InTbl.Offset(0, i).Text <> "End _TBL"
     Str = GetFilterCriteria(InTbl.Offset(0, i))
     a = i + 1
     If Str <> "" Then
        Title = InTbl.Offset(0, i).Text
        RecFilt.Offset(0, ii).Value = Title
        RecFilt.Offset(1, ii).Value = ColumnNbrToLetter(a)
        RecFilt.Offset(2, ii).Value = "•" & Str
        ii = ii + 1
     End If
     i = i + 1
  Loop
End Sub


Sub SetFiltersFromTbl(InTbl As Range, Filt_Param As Range)
  Dim FilterI As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim iOr As Integer: Dim iAnd As Integer
  'InTbl.Worksheet.ActiveCell.Offset(InTbl.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Activate
  'todo Move the ActiveCell to be in the data Filtered : BUG MICROSOFT TO SOLVE. I don t have it myself
  If InTbl.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    InTbl.Worksheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
  End If
  i = 0
  FilterI = Filt_Param.Offset(2, i).Value
  Do While Len(FilterI) > 2
     Idx_Filt = ColumnLetterToNbr(Filt_Param.Offset(1, i).Value)
     iOr = InStr(1, FilterI, "||"): iAnd = InStr(1, FilterI, "&&")
     If iAnd > 0 Then ' Case Criteria 2 with OR
         InTbl.AutoFilter Field:=Idx_Filt, Criteria1:=Mid(FilterI, 2, iAnd - 2), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=Mid(FilterI, iAnd + 2, Len(FilterI) - iAnd - 2)
     ElseIf iOr > 0 Then ' Case Criteria 2 with AND
         InTbl.AutoFilter Field:=Idx_Filt, Criteria1:=Mid(FilterI, 2, iOr - 2), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Mid(FilterI, iOr + 2, Len(FilterI) - iOr - 2)
     ElseIf CountChrInStr(FilterI, "•") = 2 Then 'Single value filter
         InTbl.AutoFilter Field:=Idx_Filt, Criteria1:=Mid(FilterI, 2, Len(FilterI) - 2), Operator:=xlFilterValues
     Else 'Array of values filter
         InTbl.AutoFilter Field:=Idx_Filt, Criteria1:=(Split(Mid(FilterI, 2, Len(FilterI) - 2), "•")), Operator:=xlFilterValues
     End If
     i = i + 1
     FilterI = Filt_Param.Offset(2, i).Text
  Loop
End Sub

Function ExtrFilterParam(StrAll As String, Id_Param As Integer)
  ExtrFilterParam = ""
  For i = 0 To Id_Param
    Idx = InStr(Idx, StrAll, "•")
    If Idx = 0 Then Exit Function:
  Loop
  ExtrFilterParam = Mid(StrAll, Idx + 1, InStr(Idx, StrAll, "•") - Idx - 1)
End Function


Function GetFilterCriteria(Rng As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim Filter As String
    Filter = ""
    On Error GoTo Finish
      'Rng.Parent.AutoFilter.Filter.count
    With Rng.Parent.AutoFilter
        If Intersect(Rng, .Range) Is Nothing Then GoTo Finish
        With .Filters(Rng.Column - .Range.Column + 1)
            If Not .On Then GoTo Finish
              On Error GoTo Finish
              Select Case .Operator
                Case xlAnd
                    Filter = .Criteria1 & "&&" & .Criteria2 & "•"
                Case xlOr
                    Filter = .Criteria1 & "||" & .Criteria2 & "•"
                Case Else
                    On Error GoTo Nxt
                    Filter = .Criteria1 & "•"
Nxt:
                    On Error GoTo Nxt2 ' Multiple Value treatment
                    For Each Criteria In .Criteria1
                        Filter = Filter & Criteria & "•"
                    Next Criteria
Nxt2:
            End Select
        End With
    End With
Finish:
GetFilterCriteria = Filter
End Function


' Plus here the custom functions  that I have self made (with ChatGPT help) :
Function ColumnNbrToLetter(columnNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim dividend As Integer
    Dim columnLetter As String
    Dim modulo As Integer

    If columnNumber < 1 Then
        ColumnNumberToLetter = "Invalid Column"
        Exit Function
    End If

    columnLetter = ""
    dividend = columnNumber

    Do
        modulo = (dividend - 1) Mod 26
        columnLetter = Chr(65 + modulo) & columnLetter
        dividend = (dividend - modulo) \ 26
    Loop While dividend > 0

    ColumnNbrToLetter = columnLetter
End Function

Function ColumnLetterToNbr(Letter As String) As Long
    Dim colNumber As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    colNumber = 0
    For i = Len(Letter) To 1 Step -1
        colNumber = colNumber + (Asc(UCase(Mid(Letter, i, 1))) - 64) * (26 ^ (Len(Letter) - i))
    Next i

    ColumnLetterToNbr = colNumber
End Function

Function CountChrInStr(StrIn As String, charToFind As String) As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim position As Long
    Count = 0
    position = InStr(1, StrIn, charToFind)
    Do While position > 0
        Count = Count + 1
        position = InStr(position + 1, StrIn, charToFind)
    Loop
    CountChrInStr = Count
End Function
```

Comment: *Youhoo! It seems that I don t have a bug when the cursor is out from the ...* please describe the error you are getting.