# Excel VBA Autofilter object not set

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that, with user input value in a determined column from a table, some rows will be inserted, each row a filldown from the original row (the active row where the user made an input).

The thing is, the macro gets trouble with filtered tables, cant shift rows up. And doesnt fill down completely when columns are hidden.

So, using [In Excel VBA, how do I save / restore a user-defined filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter), I thought to save the filter state, un filter and unhide any columns, insert the rows and reinstate the filters.

My problem is, the first time I run the macro it works, but a second will throw a **Autofilter Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set**. I honestly do not have any idea why is this happening.

I only want to be able to insert rows even if the table is filtered, and to fill down everything, format and values, from the original row.

Below is my macro:

```
Public Sub InsertRows(splitVal As Integer, keyCells As Range)

    Call pw
    Call PerformanceUp

    Dim w As Worksheet

    Set w = Worksheets("Orders")

    w.Unprotect Password

    Dim filterArray()
    Dim currentFiltRange As String
    Dim col As Integer

    ' Capture AutoFilter settings - Error starts here after second run
    With w.AutoFilter
        currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
        With .Filters
            ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
            For f = 1 To .Count
                With .Item(f)
                    If .On Then
                        filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                        If .Operator Then
                            filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next f
        End With
    End With

    'Remove AutoFilter
    w.AutoFilterMode = False
    w.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    With keyCells
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        'When filtered, can't paste and insert, so two steps
        .Offset(1).Resize(splitVal).EntireRow.Insert
        .Resize(1 + splitVal).FillDown
    End With

    'Restore Filter settings
    For col = 1 To UBound(filterArray(), 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(filterArray(col, 1)) Then
            If filterArray(col, 2) Then
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1), _
                Operator:=filterArray(col, 2), _
                Criteria2:=filterArray(col, 3)
            Else
                w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
                Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next col

ExitHandler:
        Call PerformanceDown
        w.Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
        , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
        Exit Sub


ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly
        GoTo ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesnt make any sense, I remove the filters, store them, do stuff, and afterwards restore them. I can see my table having autofilters. By the way, I saved and closed the WB and tried to run the macro and it wont work.

Comment: Stick a breakpoint in at `'Restore Filter Settings` and step through?  You may be hitting an error and skipping to `ExitHandler`.  Either way, add a check for `If w.AutoFilterMode Then` around the `With w.Autofilter` block?

Comment: For me your code runs without error multiple times, if and only if there is an AutoFilter initially set on the sheet. Otherwise `w.AutoFilter` is `Nothing` and `currentFiltRange = .Range.Address` errors.  I suggest you capture the AutoFilter status into a Boolean variable (eg `HasAF = Not w.AutoFilter Is Nothing` and wrap the AF save and restore sections in `If HasAF Then`

Comment: Then I believe I am confused about this code. I tried it with auto filter on, and with some columns filtered, but it did not work. How did you run it without errors multiple times?

Comment: FWIW `GoTo ExitHandler` should be `Resume ExitHandler`.