# Excel VBA: Error 1004 coming up randomly when inserting rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with some macros that have worked really well for a while now until recently that they started showing *Error 1004: That command cannot be used on multiple selections.* After some brainstorming, I found out that some hidden columns and rows.

**Problem:** Error 1004: That command cannot be used on multiple selections.

**When:** Running macro that deletes selected rows or inserts rows.

**Possible cause:** Filtered rows and/or columns

The InsertRows module inserts an X amount of rows, depending on the number the users gives (splitVal) and copies everything, formulas and format, from the original keycell row.

```
Sub InsertRows(ByVal splitVal As Integer, ByVal keyCells As Range, ws As Worksheet)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    PW
    ws.Unprotect Password
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    WBFast 
    With keyCells
        .Offset(1).Resize(splitVal).EntireRow.Insert
        .EntireRow.Copy .Offset(1, 0).Resize(splitVal).EntireRow 'Error happens here
    End With

ExitHandler:
    ws.Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    WBNorm
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Insert_Rows, line " & Erl & "."
    GoTo ExitHandler

End Sub
```

-

The delete table rows module, deletes the rows in a table that where selected by the user. Resulting range to be deleted will, in most cases, have filtered rows and there might be filtered columns. The error happens when it gets to the deleting part, same error as above.

```
Sub DeleteTableRows()
    'PURPOSE: Delete table row based on user's selection
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
    Call PW


    Dim rng As Range
    Dim DeleteRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim TempRng As Range
    Dim Answer As Variant
    Dim area As Range
    Dim ReProtect As Boolean
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim pasteRange As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim a As Long

    WBFast

    'Set Range Variable
      On Error GoTo InvalidSelection
        Set rng = Selection
      On Error GoTo 0


    'Unprotect Worksheet
      With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        If .ProtectContents Or ProtectDrawingObjects Or ProtectScenarios Then
          On Error GoTo InvalidPassword
          .Unprotect Password
          ReProtect = True
          On Error GoTo 0
        End If
      End With

      Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    'Loop Through each Area in Selection
      For Each area In rng.Areas
        For Each cell In area.Cells.Columns(1)
          'Is selected Cell within a table?
            InsideTable = True

          'Gather rows to delete
            If InsideTable Then
              On Error GoTo InvalidActiveCell
              Set TempRng = Intersect(cell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
              On Error GoTo 0

              If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRng = TempRng
              Else
                Set DeleteRng = Union(TempRng, DeleteRng)
              End If

            End If

        Next cell
      Next area


    'Error Handling
      If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then GoTo InvalidSelection
      If DeleteRng.Address = ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Address Then GoTo DeleteAllRows
      If ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then GoTo DeleteOnlyRow

    'Ask User To confirm delete (since this cannot be undone)
        DeleteRng.Select

        If DeleteRng.Rows.Count = 1 And DeleteRng.Areas.Count = 1 Then
          Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the currently selected table row? " & _
           " This cannot be undone...", vbYesNo, "Delete Row?")
        Else
          Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the currently selected table rows? " & _
           " This cannot be undone...", vbYesNo, "Delete Rows?")
        End If

    'Delete row (if wanted)
      If Answer = vbYes Then

        'Error 1004 happens here
        For a = DeleteRng.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print DeleteRng.Areas.Count
            DeleteRng.Areas(a).EntireRow.Delete
        Next a


        WBNorm

      End If

    'Protect Worksheet
      If ReProtect = True Then wb.Worksheets("Open Orders").Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
    Exit Sub

    'ERROR HANDLERS

InvalidActiveCell:
      MsgBox "The first cell you select must be inside an Excel Table. " & _
       "The first cell you selected was cell " & ActiveCell.Address, vbCritical, "Invalid Selection!"
      If ReProtect = True Then wb.Worksheets("Open Orders").Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
      WBNorm
      Exit Sub

InvalidSelection:
      MsgBox "You must select a cell within an Excel table", vbCritical, "Invalid Selection!"
      If ReProtect = True Then wb.Worksheets("Open Orders").Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
      WBNorm
      Exit Sub

DeleteAllRows:
      MsgBox "You cannot delete all the rows in the table. " & _
       "You must leave at least one row existing in a table", vbCritical, "Cannot Delete!"
      If ReProtect = True Then wb.Worksheets("Open Orders").Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
      WBNorm
      Exit Sub

DeleteOnlyRow:
      MsgBox "You cannot delete the only row in the table.", vbCritical, "Cannot Delete!"
      If ReProtect = True Then wb.Worksheets("Open Orders").Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
      WBNorm
      Exit Sub

InvalidPassword:
      MsgBox "Failed to unlock password with the following password: " & Password
      If ReProtect = True Then wb.Worksheets("Open Orders").Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
      WBNorm
      Exit Sub

End Sub
```

-

```
Sub WBFast()
    With ThisWorkbook.Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
End Sub

Sub WBNorm()
    With ThisWorkbook.Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

I have really tried my best in coming with an efficient way of dealing with this, and the code worked until recently, that I saw a sudden need for the users to hide columns. What must I do, to do what I want even if there are rows and columns hidden/filtered, resulting in noncontinuous ranges?

Unhiding and unfiltering is out of question. The user can set complex filters and hide lots of columns he/she doesn't need, I would like to keep those things and not taking them away.

The part about saving filters and then reapply them, I tried this macro:
[In Excel VBA, how do I save / restore a user-defined filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter) but I could not make it work.

Is there truly no way of deleting rows in non contiguous ranges?

Comment: Unhide them, run macro, then re-hide them, you could do this as part of the macro possibly - at least the unhide bit which would stop the errors...

Comment: Yeah, I would be hanged and set on fire if I did that. The workbook I am working on has 66 columns and up to 4000 rows. The user will set complex filters and hide perhaps 50 columns that specific user doesn't needs. If I went the easy way and took away those filters/hidden columns the user would have to go through all that ordeal of setting them again. Thanks for the input, Mike.

Comment: @rzenva I think that Mike means you could save all the filters/hidden rows numbers in memory, turn off the screen updating (so the user doesn't see what happened), insert the rows, re-hide/filter what you saved in memory and turn back the screen updating.

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar thought and I know there is a macro around there that saves the filters and reapply them; but I tried that already and it didn't work for me… and I had a question about it here and I didn't get any good answers.

Comment: @rzneva, how was Solar Mike supposed to know that you didn't want to unhide/unfilter things without any warning from you? I don't think this attitude of yours will bring you many answers

Comment: Which attitude? I said thanks for the input, I really meant it… I am sorry if it came the wrong way.

Comment: Hi, If you are interested, I can give you a way to find the filtered status of your range, so you can remove the filters and apply them again before and after your own subroutines. Or probably you can do it by some loops.

Comment: Please do, Mahhdy

Comment: RE your discussion about having tried something someone else suggested: You should include this kind of information in your question, with links if you have them. That will save everyone (you included) time and frustration :-)

Comment: You are right, I added the question that led me to try to save the autofilter state and then reapply them, but it never worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an application which was blown up. Most probably it was not intended to be used to this excess ( a lot of code and about 600 sheets, ends up of 14Mb).It ran well until recently it started showing RANDOMLY Error 1004.

Unprotecting the sheet seams to be a remendy:     Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect