# How to remove Criteria2 from Autofilter but keep Criteria1?

Tags: excel, vba

Row has a header and the rest rows are values:
In the following example where how can I remove just the `Criteria2` while keeping `Criteria1` intact.
`Criteria1` has been set manually and I don't know it's value when the macro is run.

```
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

sht1.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">10", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<20"
```

Comment: Have you tried removing criteria 2 ?

Comment: Clear all filters and reapply only filter 1?

Comment: "Have you tried [...]" = Best comment I've read all day!

Comment: @PeterT At the time of execution I don't know what "filter 1" is, it is set manually by the user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious I thought it was worth asking as it would be an example to show if it had been tried... I wanted to copy and edit but the smartphone won’t copy that text formatted as code.