# VBA, find last used column in the whole sheet

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

I googled a lot and found a lot of different solutions, but I need to improve the one I'm using now.

I want to find the last used column in the sheet using the find method not to consider the deleted cells.

All I want is to get the last column used, including the one in the row of the starting cell. In the image below if I use my code it will give last column = 4, because in the 2nd row data stops at column 4. Why isn't it giving 5  (header column) as result?

Thank you!!

```
With ActiveSheet
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    findlastcol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Column
Else
    findlastcol = 1
End If
End With
```

**Example Table** [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ifsk.png)

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 | Header5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Data    | Data    | Data    | Data    |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AutoFilter Kicks the Find Method

- The `Find` method with `xlFormulas` is pretty much 'bullet proof', unless there is a filter involved which is happening in your case.
- The following example shows how to do it by turning the `AutoFilter` off, which is not quite what one wants. It also shows how there were three not needed arguments. Additionally it is a different approach which does not need `CountA`.
- A proper solution would be to copy the current filter into a [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filter) object and then apply it later back. Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filters) of how to do it.

**The Code**

```
Sub testBulletProof()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
        Set rng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    End With
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        LastCol = rng.Column
    Else
        LastCol = 1
    End If
    Debug.Print LastCol
End Sub
```

- Since you might know the row where the headers are and the data will not have more columns then the header does, you could use this:

**The Code**

```
Sub testFindInRow()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Rows(1).Find(What:="*", _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    End With
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        LastCol = rng.Column
    Else
        LastCol = 1
    End If
    Debug.Print LastCol
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! In the end I had to delete filters and then apply them again, I used the code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Comment: Great! Thanks for the link. Definitely will check it out.

Comment: I realized the code I linked only works if the filter is in one column, if you have multiple columns filtered it gives an error. So in the end to count the number of columns I simply counted the number of filtered ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
Sub FindLastColumn()

Dim iLastCol As Integer

ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'Refreshing used range (may need to save wb also)

iLastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but... Be careful, this method considers also cleansed cells :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try:

```
findlastcol = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but... Be careful, this method considers also cleansed cells :)