# Excel VBA: How to save filters applied to ListObject for re-using them later

Tags: excel, vba

during my procedure I want to remove all filters applied to `ListObject`, do something else and then re-apply these filters back.

I'm struggling in the first step - save filter settings.

[`ListObject.AutoFIlter.Filters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filters) is a collecton object where [`Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filters.item) is [`Filter` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filter). I want to store properties of these filters and re-use, but getting `Run-time error '1004'`

It's because Filter property [`Criteria2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filter.criteria2) is usually not set and has value: `<Application-defined or object-defined error>`. As you can see in an image below:

[image: Watch screenshot. Shows as Criteria2 value]

**Code in a module**

```vb
Public Sub FilterManupulation()
    Dim Table As ListObject
    '...
    'save filters
    Dim Saved As Variant
    Saved = SaveTableFilters(Table)
    '...
    'disable filters
    call Table.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    '...
End Sub
```

**Function code**

```vb
Public Function SaveTableFilters(ByVal Table As ListObject) As Variant
    Dim ColumnCount As Long
    ColumnCount = Table.ListColumns.Count
    
    Dim SavedFilter() As SavedFilter 'SavedFilter is custom Class
    ReDim SavedFilter(1 To ColumnCount) 'Set array size acc. to column count
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ColumnCount
        Dim Filter As Filter
        Set Filter = Table.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i)
        'Save only filters which are On
        If Filter.On Then
            Set SavedFilter(i) = New SavedFilter
            With SavedFilter(i)
                .Criteria1 = Filter.Criteria1
                .Criteria2 = Filter.Criteria2 'This throws Run-time error '1004'
                .Operator = Filter.Operator
            End With
        End If
    Next i 
    SavedTableFilters = SavedFilter()   
End Function
```

**`SavedFilter` Class Module code**

```vb
Public Criteria1 As Variant
Public Criteria2 As Variant
Public Operator As XlAutoFilterOperator
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams, this helps. (I already saw it before, but consider it - based on top rated answer - obsolete. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

**This solution is meant for Excel versions officially supported in time of writing (01/2021).**

If you need compatibility with old (already unsupported) Excel versions see [answer in: In Excel VBA, how do I save / restore a user-defined filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15379095/11226004) by [@PhilSpencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2164215/phil-spencer)

```vb
Public Function SavedTableFilters(ByVal Table As ListObject) As Variant
    Dim ColumnCount As Long
    ColumnCount = Table.ListColumns.Count
    
    Dim SavedFilter() As SavedFilter
    ReDim SavedFilter(1 To ColumnCount)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ColumnCount
        Dim Filter As Filter
        Set Filter = Table.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(i)
        'Save only filters which are On
        If Filter.On Then
            Set SavedFilter(i) = New SavedFilter
            With SavedFilter(i)
                .Criteria1 = Filter.Criteria1
                .Operator = Filter.Operator

                On Error Resume Next 'Error handling (if error skip to next line)
                    .Criteria2 = Filter.Criteria2
                    If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 1004 Then
                        'Code what to do if other error than 1004 is thrown
                    End If
                On Error GoTo 0 'Re-set to default
            End With
        End If
    Next i
            
    SavedTableFilters = SavedFilter()
    
End Function
```

The trick is done by

- "ignoring" errors in code [`On Error Resume Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement#on-error-resume-next) while accessing
  `Filter.Criteria2`.
- All errors are "ignored" after `On Error Resume Next`, this is why there is `If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 1004` which is true in case of other error.
- [`On Error GoTo 0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement#on-error-goto-0) is return to default behavior

The first idea was to decide if to even access `Filter.Criteria2` based on [`Filter.Operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.filter.operator) [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilteroperator), but I'm not sure if it is reliable.