# How to make code that adds row work in filtered table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that adds rows on my table, it works like this.

Copy entire row based on current cell location (Red row).
[image]

Then paste it below the current cell location by adding rows, not just copying the data
[image]

Error im getting: Error 1004 - Cannot move cells in a table or filtered range

The problem is, I can't get this code to work when my table has filters, how do I do this without breaking my current code?

My code:

```
Sub INSERT_ROWS()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim MyTable As Object
    Dim RowsToAdd As Long
    RowsToAdd = Worksheets("CC").Range("B18") 'Where i get the number of rows to be added
        
    Set MyTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    
    If RowsToAdd > 0 Then
            If Not Intersect(Selection, MyTable.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            
            Dim SelectedRow As Long
            SelectedRow = Intersect(Selection, MyTable.DataBodyRange).Row - MyTable.HeaderRowRange.Row
            
            Dim RowCounter As Long
            For RowCounter = SelectedRow To SelectedRow + RowsToAdd - 2 'To place rows bellow current cell location
                MyTable.ListRows.Add Position:=RowCounter + 1
                MyTable.ListRows(RowCounter).Range.Copy Destination:=MyTable.ListRows(RowCounter + 1).Range
            Next RowCounter
        End If
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How is the behavior of your code different when filters have been applied?

Comment: Error 1004 - Cannot move cells in a table or filtered range

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195097/vba-save-autofilter-do-manual-stuff-then-reaply-filters, this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter has code for storing filter settings and then re-applying them later.  So you could maybe remove the filters after reading the settings, and then add the rows and re-apply the filters.

Comment: In my side, I tried like this : `With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` ... next line `r = ActiveCell.Row - .HeaderRowRange.Row: arr = .ListRows(r).Range.Value` this line put the value of the selected row of the table as arr variable. Next line `For i = 1 To RowsToAdd` ... next line `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert:.ListRows(r).Range.Value = arr` ... next line `next i` ... next line `end with`. It doesn't throw me an error although the table is being filtered.

Comment: @karma Your code is placing the cells above the active cell, so it is getting the header formatting, how can I modify this and put it to place the cells below the active cell?

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for the tip, I'll take a look at those posts, and try to work on my own code

Comment: @Cooper, in my side I add `col = .HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count:ColorID = ActiveCell.Interior.Color` - then inside the loop (just befor the next i) I add `ActiveCell.Resize(1, col).Interior.Color = ColorID`.