# How can I use Excel VBA to get the value of Criteria1 in field #2 of an AutoFiltered table?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I would like to populate a string variable 'x' with the current value of Criteria1 for field #2 of the autofiltered range of the current sheet.

I think I'm looking for a simplified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter/9490281#9490281) but I cannot work out how to simplify it.

The filtered table will always have headers in row 10, data is in columns A:Z, and I only care about the criteria1 and criteria2 values for column B (field #2).  The filter criteria will always be strings (not arrays or dates).

```
Sub CycleFilterSettingsFieldTWO()

Dim x As String

x= ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.field(2).criteria1 'best guess, doesn't work!
 'I've also tried ...
     'activesheet.autofilter.filters.filterarray(10,2)
     'activesheet.autofilter.filters.item(1,1)

Select Case x
    Case Is = "3"
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="4"

    Case Is = "4"
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="*" 'Show everything

    Case Else
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="3"

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cycle AutoFilter Filters

**Short**

```vb
x = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria1
```

**Example**

```vb
Sub CycleFilterSettingsFieldTWO()

    Const Col As Long = 2

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.AutoFilter.Range
        If ws.FilterMode Then
            Select Case ws.AutoFilter.Filters(Col).Criteria1
                Case "=3"
                    rg.AutoFilter Col, "4"
                Case "=4"
                    ws.ShowAllData
                Case Else
                    ws.ShowAllData
            End Select
        Else
            rg.AutoFilter Col, "3"
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Here's an example of how to loop over the filters. It is assumed that `AutoFilterMode` is `True`.

```vb
Sub LoopFiltersExample()
    
    Dim fs As Filters: Set fs = Sheet1.AutoFilter.Filters
    
    Dim f As Filter
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each f In fs
        n = n + 1
        If f.On Then
            Debug.Print n, f.Criteria1
        Else
            Debug.Print n, "Is off"
        End If
    Next f
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you for several extra tips embedded into your solution.

Comment: (The 'case else' line should be `rg.AutoFilter Col, "3")
As a follow-up question, could I have used the Object Browser to help with this, since I was an the right track with `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters` - specifically, is there a way that I could tell that 'filters' needs the column number in brackets?  I'd love to improve my skills at finding my own solution in cases like this.

Comment: FYI, I didn't know this either. I went with something like `Dim fs As Filters: Set fs = ws.AutoFilter.Filters`. Now when I wrote `fs` in the next line, I tried the dot i.e. `fs.` and the only useful property was the `.Count`. So I removed the dot and used the left parentheses i.e. `fs(` and it gave me `...Index As Long...`. So I tried the count and it gave me `10` (one for each column). Then I tried a loop: `Dim f As Filter: For Each f In fs...` but that errored on the first n so I did `Set f = fs(2): Debug.Print f.Criteria1` and it gave me `=3`. The rest was easy.

Comment: Thank you very much [Hvala vam puno] for explaining these techniques so clearly.  I will refer to these steps next time I have a similar problem.