# how to store autofilter field and Criteria1 to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

the follwing line of codes will set the filter field1 to "Ford", "GMC", "Caprice"
and field2 to "1980", "1990", "1995"

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$8:$C$712").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Ford", "GMC", "Caprice"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

ActiveSheet.Range("$B$8:$C$717").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("1980", "1990", "1995"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

I
```

would like to how to store the field and Criteria1 of autofilter in a variable so that after running some macro and setting autofiltermode off , then I can return the filter back to what it was

In fact I couldn't try any thing

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to retrieve the current settings of the filter.

ASSUMPTION: you selected values via the checkboxes. More complex filters, e.g. values between 1 and 100 or dates need a more complex code.

```vb
Public Function readCurrentFilter(af As AutoFilter) As Variant

If af.FilterMode = False Then Exit Function

With af
    Dim arrFilterSettings As Variant
    ReDim arrFilterSettings(2, .Filters.Count - 1)
        
    Dim f As Filter, i As Long
    For Each f In af.Filters
        arrFilterSettings(0, i) = f.On
        If f.On = True Then
            arrFilterSettings(1, i) = f.Criteria1
            arrFilterSettings(2, i) = f.Operator
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End With

readCurrentFilter = arrFilterSettings
End Function
```

To filter based on the previous values you can use this sub:

```vb
Public Sub setFilter(af As AutoFilter, arrFilterSettings As Variant)

Dim f As Filter, i As Long
With af.Range
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrFilterSettings, 2)
        If arrFilterSettings(0, i) = True Then
            If IsArray(arrFilterSettings(1, i)) Then 'multiple values
                .AutoFilter i + 1, arrFilterSettings(1, i), arrFilterSettings(2, i)
            Else
                .AutoFilter i + 1, arrFilterSettings(1, i)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

To test these two subs try this:

```vb
Public Sub test()
Dim af As AutoFilter
Set af = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter

Dim arrFilterSettings As Variant
arrFilterSettings = readCurrentFilter(af)

af.ShowAllData

setFilter af, arrFilterSettings

End Sub
```

You might need to add error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the filter criteria into a variable array something like this:

```
savedfilter1 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(1).Criteria1
savedfilter2 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria1
```

To restore values

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$8:$C$712").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=savedfilter1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$8:$C$712").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=savedfilter2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```